# UISegmentedControl accessibility hint

Tags: accessibility, uisegmentedcontrol

in Xcode 6.1 and base sdk 8.0 deployment 7.1

Im trying to set the accessibility label, value and hint for the segments. I've checked the 
[How do I set the accesibility label for a particular segment of a UISegmentedControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833967/how-do-i-set-the-accesibility-label-for-a-particular-segment-of-a-uisegmentedcon)

but that too does not work on the device. on setting those for the label or the image, the voiceover only states the accessibilityLabel and not the value or the hint.

How can we get to voice the value and the hint?

Comment: It sounds to me like you might be using a segmented control outside of the way iOS intends it to be used.  If you describe your scenario a little more, instead of your problem, we might be able to provide alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of what you want to accomplish, iOS won't let you do it.  For segmented controls, iOS behaves in a custom way.  Even when you attempt to override the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol, things with the iOS framework override the behavior you're attempting to get.  I attempted to override both the UIAccesssibilityElement and UIAccessibilityContainer protocols.  What stuck out to me, was that my overriden

```
- (NSString*)accessibilityHint { return @"This is my hint";}
```

function was being called, and yet the hint value was still being ignored.  If you notice, the segments are read out as such

```
(label) The title for the segment
(trait) button
(hint) 1 of 2
```

Then the last part reads "# of #".  I believe, what is happening is that the framework is ignoring any user supplied hint, and using segment count and maximum number of segments in place of the hint.  Since I was able to successfully override the protocol, and STILL have it behave this way, I believe that you are stuck.  If you provide more information about what your User Experience needs are, I'd be happy to suggest alternatives.

EDIT: 
This is further supported by the fact that, if you are in the accessibility pain, in interface builder.  When you select a segmented control for editing, the hint and label disappear.  They don't intend for you to change these strings for these types of controls.  Most likely because on the backend, they are handling this particular type of UI Object in a custom manner that can't be, or doesn't make sense to be, overridden.

Answer (score 1):

A little clarification here. The Apple Doc is correct in that you can programmatically set each segment to have an Accessibility label that is different from its visual label:

```
NSString *title = @”Rating”;
title.accessibilityLabel = @”Sort by highest rated”;
[segmentedControl insertedSegmentedWithTitle:title];
```

What you *can't* do is overrider the accessibility hint. That seems to be system generated as '1 of 4' or whatever. But by making the accessibility label better, you can reduce the need for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is documented, but not sure if it's up-to-date.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISegmentedControl-SW16