# Test if object is an instance of class UISegment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

So I'm doing some ugly hacks to modify the appearance of individual segments in a `UISegmentedControl`. When I walk down the `UISegmentedControl`'s subview array and print each immediate subview's class name, I can see there are instances of `UISegment` for each segment in the control:

```
for (UIView *view in [[self segments] subviews])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([view class]));
}
```

Now apparently Xcode can't resolve this class, so I can't use the familiar `[view isKindOfClass:[UISegment class]]`.

I assumed I was just missing a header to include, but I also [can't find any docs for it on Apple's developer reference site](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=UISegment&platform=iOS).

So how would I go about testing if an object is an instance of `UISegment`? And what exactly is this class - whose name can be resolved at run-time but not at compile-time?

---

**edit**

What I'm trying to achieve is a clear indication that a particular segment is enabled or disabled. For instance, when I disable an entire `UISegmentedControl`, the following works great to update both selected and unselected segment colors/fonts:

```
- (void)setIsEnabled:(BOOL)isEnabled
{
    [super setIsEnabled:isEnabled];

    // be careful and ensure you use the isEnabled getter because it takes isEnabledForConfiguration into account
    [[self segments] setUserInteractionEnabled:[self isEnabled]];

    [[self segments] setTintColor:[self interactionColor]];

    [[self segments] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self enabledTextColor]
                                                                        forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName]
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

But sometimes only a subset of the segments should be disabled, and I would like to visually make that apparent (the `-(void)setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex:` method doesn't seem to have any visible effect).

So I've found that I can modify these `UISegment` subviews to achieve the visual updates (nasty hack, isn't guaranteed to work in the future, I know...).

To *try* protecting against those future API changes, I've done my best to implement a flexible way to grab a reference to the `UISegment` objects by segment index.

First, I grab the title of the segment at the input segment index, then traverse all the way down the `UISegmentedControl` view hierarchy until I find something that responds to the `text` selector and whose `text` value equals the title. That view always seems to be a `UISegmentLabel` (which is another private class!), and his superview is the `UISegment` I'm looking for. So I've come up with:

```
- (UIView *)getSegmentAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSString *title = [[self segments] titleForSegmentAtIndex:index];
    id segment = nil;

    if (nil != title && 0 < [[EFBGlobalUtil trimWhitespace:title] length])
    {
        segment = [[EFBGlobalUtil viewWithCondition:^BOOL(UIView *view)
        {
            return [view respondsToSelector:@selector(text)] && [title isEqualToString:[view valueForKey:NSStringize(text)]];
        }
        inView:[self segments]] /* this dude -> */superview];
    }
    return segment;
}
```

The question really stems from that `superview` getter I stuck on the end. I would like to verify the superview is actually a `UISegment`, but the solution to that will also help me check for `UISegmentLabel` objects as well (instead of the `text` selector).

---

And for reference, here's the `+(void)viewWithCondition:inView:` utility routine:

```
+ (UIView *)viewWithCondition:(BOOL (^)(UIView *view))condition inView:(UIView *)view
{
    // non-recursive BFS traversal of a view hierarchy until specified UIView matching condition is found

    NSMutableArray<UIView *> *stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:view, nil];
    UIView *curr;

    while ([stack count] > 0)
    {
        curr = [stack firstObject];
        [stack removeObject:curr];

        if (condition((UIView *)curr))
        {
            return (UIView *)curr;
        }

        [stack addObjectsFromArray:[curr subviews]];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: It's a private class.  You can check it with `[... isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISegment")]` but that may get your app rejected for using private api or stop working in the future if apple changes the internal class name or structure.

Comment: Can you explain more of what you're trying to achieve, why do you need to test for instance of class UISegment?

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin enjoy reading my novel of an explanation :)

Comment: LOL:) nice! So is this SegmentedControl custom? did you subclass it, or you're using the original one? Cause if you subclass it, you can change the appearance of the segments on setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex: if you overwrite it, no?!

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin Not subclassing it - just a regular `UISegmentedControl` member of a `UIVew` subclass. But using that method sounds like a much better solution than what I'm doing, thanks!