# Why is the subviews property of UISegmentedControl returning more values than the numberOfSegments property?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

I've got a bit of a bug that's causing a crash. I need to apply accessibility features to the segments in a `UISegmentedControl`.

As far as I know, the only way to access segments from a `UISegmentedControl` is through its `subviews` property, which should return an array of type `UISegment`.

But with two segments on the segmented control, `subviews` is returning two `UISegment`s and two `UIImageView`s for a total of four values.

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

    func applyAccessibiltyFeatures() {

        // subviews should return an array of type UISegment
        for (index, view) in self.subviews.enumerated() {

            // This line crashes
            if let title = self.titleForSegment(at: index) {

                // Do something with accessibility
                view.doSomething(title: title)

            }     
        }
    }
}
```

The crash is caused by trying to access the title for a `UISegment` that doesn't exist. It's out of bounds because the `subviews` property returns four values even though there are only two segments in the segmented control. (Two `UISegments` and two `UIImageViews`.)

I've got a band-aid fix that stops the crash, but I can't guarantee that the accessibility features are being activated.

```
func applyAccessibiltyFeatures() {

        // This guarantees that we don't go out of bounds, but 
        //if the first two subviews are the UIImageViews, then it doesn't matter
        for index in 0..<self.numberOfSegments {
            let view = self.subviews[index]

            if let title = self.titleForSegment(at: index) {

                // Do something with accessibility
                view.doSomething(title: title)

            }     
        }
    }
```

I've tried using `contactMap` to filter the subviews down to just `UISegment`s, but `UISegment` is private and unaccessible.

Why could the subviews property be returning an extra two values?

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833967/how-do-i-set-the-accessibility-label-for-a-particular-segment-of-a-uisegmentedco?r=SearchResults&s=2|88.4901 but it  depends on what accessibility you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. There are some similarities, but the root of my issue is that the subviews property is returning too many values. I don't see anything about that in the linked question. Definitely gives me some more to think about though.